# Kafka cluster streams timeouts at high input

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm running an Kafka cluster with 7 nodes and a lot of stream processing. Now I see infrequent errors in my Kafka Streams applications like at high input rates:

```
[2018-07-23 14:44:24,351] ERROR task [0_5] Error sending record to topic topic-name. No more offsets will be recorded for this task and the exception will eventually be thrown (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl) org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 13 record(s) for topic-name-3: 60060 ms has passed since last append

[2018-07-23 14:44:31,021] ERROR stream-thread [StreamThread-2] Failed to commit StreamTask 0_5 state: (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread) org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_5] exception caught when producing at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.checkForException(RecordCollectorImpl.java:121) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.flush(RecordCollectorImpl.java:129) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask$1.run(StreamTask.java:76) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:188) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:281) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitOne(StreamThread.java:807) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitAll(StreamThread.java:794) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:769) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:647) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:361) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 13 record(s) for topic-name-3: 60060 ms has passed since last append

[2018-07-23 14:44:31,033] ERROR stream-thread [StreamThread-2] Failed while executing StreamTask 0_5 due to flush state: (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread) org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_5] exception caught when producing at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.checkForException(RecordCollectorImpl.java:121) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.flush(RecordCollectorImpl.java:129) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:423) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$4.apply(StreamThread.java:555) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.performOnTasks(StreamThread.java:501) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.flushAllState(StreamThread.java:551) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.shutdownTasksAndState(StreamThread.java:449) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.shutdown(StreamThread.java:391) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:372) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 13 record(s) for topic-name-3: 60060 ms has passed since last append

[2018-07-23 14:44:31,039] WARN stream-thread [StreamThread-2] Unexpected state transition from RUNNING to NOT_RUNNING. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread) Exception in thread "StreamThread-2" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_5] exception caught when producing at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.checkForException(RecordCollectorImpl.java:121) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.flush(RecordCollectorImpl.java:129) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask$1.run(StreamTask.java:76) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:188) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:281) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitOne(StreamThread.java:807) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitAll(StreamThread.java:794) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:769) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:647) at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:361) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 13 record(s) for topic-name-3: 60060 ms has passed since last append
```

If I reduce the input rate (from 20k to 10k events/s) the errors are gone away. So obviously I'm reaching any sort of limit. I have played around with different options (request.timeout.ms, linger.ms and batch.size) but every time the same result.

Comment: please let us know what config values you have for `replication.factor` and `producer.acks` properties? also what number of partitions per topic?

Comment: topics: 7 partitions with 3 replicas, kafka streams: default config

Comment: try to test your app with high load using default `replication.factor` value (by default is 1). 7 partitions might be small amount for your load, try to increase.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have reached some kind of limit. Based on the message `60060 ms has passed since last append` I'd assume it's writher thread starvation due to high load, so disk would be the first thing to check:

- disk usage - if you're reaching write speed limit, switching from hdd to ssd might help
- load distribution - is your traffic split +- equally to all nodes?
- CPU load - lots of processing can

Comment: Thanks for the input, we use SSDs, input and load is distributed equally and CPU usage around 50% on each node.

Answer (score 0):

we had similar issue.
in our case we had the following configuration for replication and acknowledgement:

```
replication.factor: 3
producer.acks: all
```

and under high load the same error occurred multiple times `TimeoutException: Expiring N record(s) for topic: N ms has passed since last append`.

after removing our custom `replication.factor` and `producer.acks` configs (so we now using default values), and this error has disapearred. 
Definitely it takes much more time on producer side until leader will receive full set of in-sync replicas to acknowledge the record, and until records replicated with specified `replication.factor`. 
You will be slightly less protected on fault tolerance with default values.

Also potentially consider to increase the number of partitions per topic and number of application nodes (in which your kafka stream logic processed).

Comment: Thanks, I used the defaults, but will try different config options